# What is the default layout height (dp) of Material Slider?

Tags: android, slider, material-components-android

I just want to know the default value of the layout height in dp of Material Slider. (Or how to know such values?)

Comment: 48dp - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/res/values/dimens.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig into the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/336042dd0ddd58fdd2f4154ec4c68c48527f11bb/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/BaseSlider.java#L387) of Material Slider, you can find this line:

```
widgetHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_widget_height);
```

This `widgetHeight` is approximately what I looked for. Based on `widgetHeight`, `onMeasure` will `makeMeasureSpec`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
        widgetHeight
            + (labelBehavior == LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS ? labels.get(0).getIntrinsicHeight() : 0),
        MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

When `LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS` is false, the measured size is just the `widgetHeight`.

So the `widgetHeight` in dp is defined as `R.dimen.mtrl_slider_widget_height` which is `48dp` in the [R.dimen](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/res/values/dimens.xml) just as @Pawel suggested.

```
Log.d("slider height", getResources().getString(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_widget_height));
```

Answer (score 0):

The default height for Material Slider is `4dp` and you can know all about it and further more using the material IO website.

Here is a link for your further reference
https://material.io/components/sliders/android#discrete-slider

Comment: No, `4dp` is track size. I want to know the layout size.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by the layout @hata?

Comment: The height of its layout bound.